# PHP variable into vb 6.0

Tags: php, vb6

Hello I'm trying to pass a value from `php` to `vb 6.0`.

Using a `batch` file or `.exe` I don't know if its applicable.

I tried `exec` and `shell_exec` but still no luck.

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$var1= $this->request->data['var1'];
$var2= $this->request->data['var2']; 
$var3= $this->request->data['var3']; 

$output = exec('run');

debug($output);
echo getcwd();
```

and my vb

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim var1 As String
        Dim varArray As Array
        Dim var2 As String
        var1 = Console.ReadLine()
        varArray = Split(var1, " ")
        Console.WriteLine("1st: " + varArray(0) + " 2nd: " + varArray(1) + " 3rd: " + varArray(2))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Where is this php code? Is it running on an external webserver?

Comment: And you want your php script to launch a vb application? Or does the vb application call the php script?

Comment: I want to launch a vb application.

Comment: You should be able to use exec to execute your .exe files. Note: this will only work on a windows machine and it will only work with console applications that require no extra input after execution. Can I ask what you application does?

Comment: ok I will use only windows machine. the application will regenerate a csv files and those files will transfer inside the web app folder.

Comment: Is the program working? If not, can you show us some code? We can't do much with what you told us.

Comment: I showed my current code

Comment: How can you be sure that the vb code has never ran? You will never see the `console.WriteLine` because you don't use the output in either vb or php.

Comment: the vb is running I want to do right now is to pass the 3 value of php variable to that vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer it explains how to get the value from parameters

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?517473-Classic-VB-How-can-I-use-command-line-parameters-in-my-program

Answer (score 0):

VB6 is not a console program. Nor does it have a console object. The .NET framework does. It's hard to work out what you are trying to do as you've put together random code.

You need to say what the problem is, not ask why random code doesn't work (why would it work?).

Use VB6's command() function to return command line and use split to convert into an array.

Even though I don't know PHP I bothered to look up the reference.

```
$output = exec('run');
```

means you are running a program called Run in the current directory or path?????

You console.writeline (which won't work) but VB6 doesn't have either a console (and hence a console object).

You seem to know neither PHP, VB6 or VB.NET.

Comment: thank you for your answer so what  I need to pass some value and the vb will generate the csv using the value that I get from php?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that exec is the right php command. But whatever is execute

```
"c:\somefolder\vbprogram.exe" "parameter1" "Parameter2", ..., "ParameterN"
```

The only thing you can get back from a GUI program is the exit code.